# Block Allocation in Fixed-Size Block Allocator

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, assembly

The following routine is the block-allocation procedure in a fixed-size allocator being written for library use. It is designed to be accessed from C++ (the un-mangled symbol name is `void * Superblock::alloc_block()`). The performance of this routine is the critical to the library; and I, with almost no prior experience in assembly, am looking for suggestions about performance and also any holes in the logic. It seems to be working correctly right now, but I'm worried about edge cases.

Execution context: written for x86_64 System V abi, full allocator may be found here: https://github.com/cmura81/experimental-allocator.

**alloc_sb_alloc_block.s**:

```
.globl __ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv

// 'this is passed in %rdi
// Variables:
//    this->beginning = 0(%rdi) +8
//    this->last_privately_freed_block = 8(%rdi) +8
//    this->last_publicly_freed_block = 16(%rdi) +8
//    this->block_size = 24(%rdi) +2
//    this->free_blocks = 26(%rdi) +2
//    this->max_blocks = 28(%rdi) +2

__ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv:
  xorq %rcx, %rcx
  // this->beginning -> rsi
  movq 0(%rdi), %rsi
  // allocated_block = this->last_privately_freed_block
  movq 8(%rdi), %rax
  // if this->last_privately_freed_block == NULL
  testq %rax, %rax
  jz __ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_pubchalloc
  // this->free_blocks--
  decw 26(%rdi)

  // Move 2 bytes from rax into edx
  movzwl (%rax), %edx
  notw %dx
  jz __ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_nbi_ffff
  notw %dx
  movslq %edx, %rcx
  // this->last_privately_freed_block = this->beginning + next_block_index
  addq %rcx, %rsi
  movq %rsi, 8(%rdi)

  ret
__ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_nbi_ffff:
  movq $0, 8(%rdi)
  ret
__ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_pubchalloc:
  movq 16(%rdi), %rax
  // if this->last_publicly_freed_block == NULL
  testq %rax, %rax
  jz __ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_noalloc
  // this->free_blocks--
  decw 26(%rdi)

  // if *(uint16_t)(this->last_publicly_freed_block + next_block_index) == 0xFFFF
  movzwl (%rax), %edx
  notw %dx
  jz __ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_pubnbi_ffff
  notw %dx
  movslq %edx, %rcx
  // this->last_privately_freed_block = this->beginning + next_block_index
  addq %rcx, %rsi
  movq %rsi, 16(%rdi)
  ret
__ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_pubnbi_ffff:
  movq $0, 8(%rdi)
  ret
__ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_noalloc:
  movq $0, %rax
  ret
```

Comment: Don't you have some unit tests for the edge cases?  Perhaps you should have posted them - it's often easier to find gaps in the testing than to spot the errors in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These comments all have to do with optimization, not "logic holes."  Also, they are written without having tested them.  Obviously you'll want to both ensure correct function, and profile to see if they actually improve anything.

1) As an obvious first step:

```
xorq %rcx, %rcx
```

can be done as

```
xorq %ecx, %ecx
```

It produces the same effect, but it's 1 byte shorter.

2) It looks like you are using `notw %dx` (in 2 different places) to see if dx is 0xffff?  I might try `cmp $0xffff, %dx` instead.  It's 2 bytes longer, but you don't have to "put it back" if it's not (the extra `notw %dx` costs 3 bytes).

3) (Check me on this one) You are using `movslq %edx, %rcx` to move edx to rcx.  However because of how you populate edx, I believe it already clears the upper bits.  Such being the case, a simple `movq %rdx, %rcx` might suffice.

4) The `__ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_pubchalloc` loop should probably have a `pause` inserted.  Perhaps something like this:

```
__ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_pubchalloc2:
  pause
__ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_pubchalloc:
  movq 16(%rdi), %rax
  // if this->last_publicly_freed_block == NULL
  testq %rax, %rax
  jz __ZN10Superblock11alloc_blockEv.i_pubchalloc2
```

See the docs on `pause` for why this is a good idea.

These are all pretty nitpicky.  Since there's only the 1 loop, there's just not that much to optimize.

Comment: Actually, `.i_pubchalloc` isn't a loop - it was a typo on my part; should have been `.i_noalloc`, never got noticed because it's an extremely low-probability event

Comment: Ahh.  I just assumed it was a multi-threading thing.